# JBoss Clustering: how to find / list all members forming the cluster

Tags: java, jboss, jboss5.x

I have several instances of JBoss 5.1 running in clustered mode.

I need to find out a way how to programatacally get a list of all nodes/members (host:port) forming the cluster. This code is supposed to run inside an EJB container.

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this info programatically by querying the JMX MBean server. You will need to query the MBean `jboss:partition=DefaultPartition,service=HAPartition` and look for the value of the attribute `CurrentView`. The `CurrentView` will provide the current nodes in the cluster along with their host/IP address. You can also verify this data by matching it up against the data from the `jmx-console` for the same MBean.

You can put this logic inside an EJB. One catch you need to be aware of is that you do not want your EJB to be deployed before the clustering service has been deployed and started. Otherwise  your EJB might throw exceptions (eg. `InstanceNotFoundException`). Therefore, add a `depends` clause for the clustering MBean (`jboss:service=DefaultPartition`) in your `jboss-web.xml` for your EJB deployment package.

Comment: Thanks, it works! But the solution seems to be JBoss5-specific. I am just wondering if there is any reliable JBoss version agnostic solution, or even  application server agnostic. I mean, that it would be greate if the same code works on JBoss 5, 6, 7

Comment: Well majority of the code would remain same, main differences are the name of the MBeans and attrbiutes between AS5 and AS7. So you can store that in a properties file or some other confgurable manner like as an argument to your apo.

Answer (score 0):

You can find out the clustering members using a variety of frameworks including JGroups, Infinispan, mod_cluster and JMX. Although this [tutorial](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-cluster/jboss-cluster-discover-cluster-members) has been written for the AS7 I believe that most of it can be useful also for AS5 users.
Regards